# How do I grant read access for a user to a database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, t-sql, ssms

I want to grant access to a user to a specific database with read and write access. The user is already available in the domain but not in the DB.

So, how can I give them that access with creating a new user and password?

Someone told me that it can be done with only specifying the user, domain & the DB that you want to give the user the access to without needing to create a new user and password.

This is the old way that I was implementing. It works but it creates a new login and user rather than using the one that is available in the domain:

```
use DBName;
create login a_2 with password='Aa123';
create user a_2 for login a_2;
grant insert to a_2;
grant select to a_2;
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This is a two-step process:

1. you need to create a **login** to SQL Server for that user, based on its Windows account

   ```
   CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<loginName>] FROM WINDOWS;
   ```
2. you need to grant this login permission to access a database:

   ```
   USE (your database)
   CREATE USER (username) FOR LOGIN (your login name)
   ```

Once you have that user in your database, you can give it any rights you want, e.g. you could assign it the `db_datareader` database role to read all tables.

```
USE (your database)
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '(your user name)'
```

Comment: unfortunatlly, I can't v=create the login based on the windows account. since, the account for the user it only available on the domain it doesn't availble on the windows account... So, when I use "from windows" it said that --> "Windows NT user or group 'aa.us\bb' not found. Check the name again.
" !!! 
it can't see it... So, is there is a way to let it look in the domain rather than the windows account ??

Note:
don't worry, I write my own domain & login name ;)

Thanks alot;)

Comment: Never mind 'marc_s'... I solved the problem... I seam I was writting the domain name wrong, now its working :)  Thanks alot;)

Comment: I always end up here when I forget to 'create user for login"!! ;) +1

Comment: Thank you. Why 10 pages of official Microsoft doecumentation NEVER show that example ?

Comment: @Jurion because Microsoft documentation is just the *best*