# create user for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code below allow me to create a user in sql server through the use of a query. it currently creates a user profile but it gives the user access to all of the databases on the server. I would only like them to have Access to the "TEST" database how would i go about doing this

```
CREATE LOGIN [SupportUser]
WITH PASSWORD=N'SupportUser',
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master],
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english],
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF,
CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

Comment: You need to do it with sql command line? If not just use the maangement studio where you can set the user roles.

Comment: I am already setting the roles but only want the user to access that one datbase

Comment: I think if you want that user to have access to only and only TEST database then DEFAULT_DATABASE should also be TEST not MASTER.

Comment: Your script creates a login, not a user, and unless you added it to the `sysadmin` role or another server role then by default it has no access to any user databases. So I think your question is really "how do I grant a login access to a specific database"? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688880/how-do-i-grant-read-access-for-a-user-to-a-database-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE LOGIN [SupportUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'SupportUser', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MASTER], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [TEST]
GO
CREATE USER [SupportUser] FOR LOGIN [SupportUser]
GO
USE [TEST]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'SupportUser'
GO
USE [TEST]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'SupportUser'
GO
USE [TEST]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ddladmin', N'SupportUser'
GO
```

Comment: What schema this use gets when you use this? Default dbo. ?

Comment: Yes. Since question doesn't mention specifics about what level of access to database is required, I am assuming that user will have READ, WRITE and Execute permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE LOGIN [SupportUser] 
WITH PASSWORD=N'SupportUser', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, 
CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [TEST]
GO
CREATE USER [SupportUser] FOR LOGIN [SupportUser]
GO
use [TEST]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[myView] TO [SupportUser]
GO
```