# SQL Server: grant all users read access to a database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an easy way to grant any authenticated user (everyone) access (read) to a given database?

Comment: simple way is EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'USerNAme'        but here username is required , if need all user at a time then make a  sp which executed auto with new db user creation

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688880/how-do-i-grant-read-access-for-a-user-to-a-database-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to enable the guest user and add it to the db_datareader fixed database role:

```
USE YourDatabase;
CREATE USER guest;
ALTER ROLE db_dataReader ADD MEMBER guest;
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks Dan!