# Copying a small database in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a small SQL server 2014 database that simply has just 3 tables and some information in them for a school group project and am wondering what the easiest way would be to have a group member be able to access the database rather then manually copying down all the information from each row and column. We wouldnt be changing any information in the database. Thanks.

Comment: Give them read access....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I grant read access for a user to a database in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688880/how-do-i-grant-read-access-for-a-user-to-a-database-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a database role. After you create the role add each person that needs access to that role then grant that role read access to each table. This way if a person in that group no longer needs access you can just remove them from the role and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a school project I am assuming that the SQL Server database is a local DB and not on a shared server.  You could perform a [backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510(v=sql.120).aspx) and [restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429(v=sql.120).aspx) where you back up the database on your machine and send them the back up files and they can use them to perform a restore to create the database on wherever.